# How can I get a after and before match in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to get an after and before match in a string.

For example, using the following string:

```
"Hello I am Jim!"
```

with the search string being: `"I am"`, the match before the search string should be: `"Hello"` and the match after should be: `"Jim!"`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> before, after = "Hello I am Jim!".split("I am")
>>> before
'Hello '
>>> after
' Jim!'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) which does exactly this:

> `S.rpartition(sep) -> (head, sep, tail)`
>
> Search for the separator `sep` in `S`, starting at the end of `S`, and return the part before it, the separator itself, and the part after it.

So, using your example string:

```
before, search_str, after = "Hello I am Jim!".partition("I am ")
```

Now `before`, `search_str` and `after` are:

```
>>> print(before)
Hello 
>>> print(search_str)
I am
>>> print(after)
Jim!
```

`str.partition` also grabs the *separator* for you as the middle element in the returned tuple. If you don't require that, `str.split(separator)` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is a good way to appeal, but you can also use the python string operation find the most basic operation to get the same point.

```
s = "Hello I am Jim!"
print s.find('I am')
for i in range(s.find('I am')):
    print s[i],
for i in range(s.find('I am')+len('I am'),len(s)):
    print s[i],
```

---

```
python team.py 
6
H e l l o     J i m !
```

In a variety of ways to achieve, then choose the most simple approach

Answer (score -1):

Here is the another way:

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = "Hello I am Jim!"
>>> before, after = re.split(" I am ", str1)
>>> before
'Hello'
>>> after
'Jim!'
```

Comment: Bringing in regex functionality for an exact match, with no explanation, just reduces performance and invites bugs.